# How to set up Fine-Uploader plugin in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, fine-uploader

I'm trying to make a multiple file upload using fine-uploader. I have been searching of a working example using CI but can't find it. This code taken from the fine uploader **[demos](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html)**.

html:

```
<div id='fine-uploader-validation'></div>
```

script template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-validation">
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
            <div>Select files</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
</script>
```

javascript:

```
var restrictedUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element : document.getElementById("fine-uploader-validation"),
        template: 'qq-template-validation',
        request : {
            //endpoint: '<?php //printbase_url(); ?>complaint/saveadd'

        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
            }
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'txt'],
            itemLimit: 3,
            sizeLimit: 51200 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
        }
    });
```

My question:

1. How to merge the script template to the div in html? I put the text in script template into the div in html but not working.
2. How to set up this in CodeIgniter (especially the script that targetting the CI controller)? or at least please refer me a link to an example of fine-uploader using CodeIgniter.
3. Where should I put an alert to alerting uploaded file name?

Comment: [Here's a github issue discussion with an example](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/174). If you scroll to the bottom it has [link to a gist that fairly complete](https://gist.github.com/weboAp/1254273). It's for CI 2 though.